# Can I use my phone as a bluetooth game controller for my computer?

Tags: bluetooth, game-controllers

I've seen [BT Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droidbean.btcontrollerfull&hl=en) but I think it only allows users to use their android as remote for other androids. I just want to use my phone as a bluetooth controller with **up**, **down**, **left**, **right**, **L**, **R**, **start**, **select**, **A**, **B** buttons for my computer. Is there an app that makes this a possibility?

Basically, there are generic bluetooth game controllers that can be bought on stores. I was wondering if I can make my Android phone act like such and be used on computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nJoy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nemex.nJoy&feature=search_result) is a very good app as well, it uses WiFi but you can just use your own hotspot if you're not using WiFi atm and turn off data if you don't want extra charges.

Comment: I think nJoy is the thing I'm looking for! :)

Comment: Glad you like it... It's customizable per-game and it has some cool features including an extra 2 button setting for gaming. Enjoy!

Comment: I don't think this is an answer for `[bluetooth]`(!) question.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned which types of games you need this for but there are several possible options:

[Gmote 2.0](http://www.gmote.org/), which is a client/server type system which would let you use your Android tablet to control your computer.

[RemoteDroid](http://www.remotedroid.net/), which is similar to Gmote, it also uses a client/server system.

[GRemotePro](http://gbmsoftware.com/) may be the right choice for you as it is but you need to pay for the server software. It is [specifically advertised as being for game control](http://gbmsoftware.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22&catid=5&Itemid=18).

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of apps available on the market. Some examples include...

- [BT Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droidbean.btcontroller): "BT Controller allows you to use your android device as a gamepad controller for any other android device." (well, you already saw this)
- [Bluetooth Remote PC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.rozkovec.android): "Bluetooth Remote PC is an app which allow you to remotely control your PC.
  Get access to the computer and use your favourite programs from distance. You can control mouse, keyboard, multimedia, presentation or power system commands."
- [PC Remote Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silicmobile.pcremotecontroller) (doesn't use Bluetooth, but rather WiFi)
- **[BlueControl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gundel.bluecontrol) looks like exactly matching your request:** "Blue Control is a basic universal Remote Control
  for Blue-Tooth enabled serial devices such as
  Blue Tooth modules connected to a micro-controller.
  For each button pressed the corresponding ASCII code
  for the label will be sent. For example pressing
  buttons A-H will send the charactes "a" - "h".
  The up, down, left, right, and center buttons will send
  "U","D","L","R", and "C" characters. Hopefully this
  will inspire people to create alot of fun Blue-Tooth Controlled devices."

A lot more Remote-Control apps can be found e.g. in [this listing at AndroidPIT (Google translated)](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F410034%2FRemote-Droide-1-Den-PC-fernsteuern) ([original link](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/410034/)). Though descriptions are in German, the general groupings and items should be recognizable ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are questions on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177186/is-it-possible-to-make-a-computer-behave-as-a-bluetooth-hid-device) and [Serverfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177186/is-it-possible-to-make-a-computer-behave-as-a-bluetooth-hid-device) regarding the same topic but for regular linux. Some of them may apply, however they're not production ready and definitely need adjustment for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Wand Player, it is described as **"a console right in your phone that lets you play games on any screen".**

http://www.wanderplayer.com/

You can even email the developers with any questions you may have

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Aio Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.allinoneremote)?

It supports controlling PC, another Android device.
Supports Windows, Linux, Mac
Supports WiFi, Bluetooth
Supports custom remote design and share remotes with all users around the world.

What do you need more than that?

Comment: What's your relationship with this software? Are you the developer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [GestureWorks Gameplay](https://gameplay.gestureworks.com). It's a fully-fledged utility for creating controller overlays on touchscreens, but they also have an Android app that's free with the utility - it can use keyboard controls or XInput and is customizable so you can make whatever kind of gamepad you like.

Answer (score 0):

Download "PC Remote" from Play Store. It's free. It can use Wi-Fi but it can also be connected with Bluetooth. It has many types of game controllers in it for different types of games like fighting type, shooting type, racing type and flying type and more. .

Comment: Please don't recommend specific apps here, it is considered off-topic. Instead, flag the question as such for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most complete program I have used so far (and I've tried many) is called Monect.  I can't remember if it is able to connect through bluetooth...but...I had no issues with it when it was connected using wi-fi which, of course, is pretty common technology.  There are a vast array of features included.  There are two main editions:

```
       1. Monect PC REMOTE(free)  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monect.portable&hl=en


       2. Monect PC REMOTE VIP ($5.28)   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monect.vipportable&hl=en
```

I bought the VIP edition, which included features which utilized my phone's sensors so I could tilt-to-steer in my racing games on my PC.  The remote pc control features were buggy from time to time though.  All in all...if your looking for an app to control your PC games with...this is the app for you.  Note: Some phones may not have the necessary sensor for certain features.  Worth a try either way.  Good luck!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can try [Androg Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codscout.agcf).

Comment: Could you please include some details on your recommendation? What makes it a good choice?